# Rails 4 Devise missing interpolation argument :authentication_keys in "Invalid %{authentication_keys} or password." ({:resource_name=>:user} given)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have Devise configured for my `user` model. For the past few days `devise` worked perfectly fine for me. It is working now also for correct email and pasword. But the problem is when I enter wrong email or password then instead of redirecting to the login page I get the error:

> I18n::MissingInterpolationArgument at /users/sign_in missing
>   interpolation argument :authentication_keys in "Invalid
>   %{authentication_keys} or password." ({:resource_name=>:user} given)

I checked in my `devise.rb` file, the line `config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]` is commented. I really don't have any idea how to solve this error and redirect to `devise` login page.

Answer (score 0):

I used this helper and got that error too (with rails 5.2.1, devise 4.5.0)

app/helpers/devise_helper.rb

```
  def devise_error_messages!
    flash_alerts = []
    error_key = 'errors.messages.not_saved'

    if !flash.empty?
      flash_alerts.push(flash[:error]) if flash[:error]
      flash_alerts.push(flash[:alert]) if flash[:alert]
      flash_alerts.push(flash[:notice]) if flash[:notice]
      error_key = 'devise.failure.invalid'
    end

    return "" if resource.errors.empty? && flash_alerts.empty?
    errors = resource.errors.empty? ? flash_alerts : resource.errors.full_messages

    messages = errors.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    sentence = I18n.t(error_key, :count    => errors.count,
                                 :resource => 
                                        resource.class.model_name.human.downcase)

    html = <<-HTML
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>#{sentence}</h2>
      <ul>#{messages}</ul>
    </div>
    HTML

    html.html_safe
  end
```

I'd have a look on the line which handles translation `I18n.t` or skip the helper at all as workaround